# Check if UINavigationItem title is truncated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, user-interface

I want to check whether the title of a `UINavigationItem` is truncated.

I set the title like this: `self.navigationItem.title = whatever`.

I know I can check if the text in a `UILabel` is truncated like this:

```
CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"myfont" size:18.0]];
if (size.width > label.bounds.size.width) {
    // set a shorter title
}
```

And I can even find the `UINavigationItemView` object in which the title is displayed like so:

```
UIView *navItemView;
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationItemView")]) {
        navItemView = view;
    }
}
```

But I cannot apply this method to the `navItemView` because is always seems to have a width of exactly 58, which is much less than the title in it, so according to that, it would appear that the title is truncated, even when it isn't.

So, my question comes down to this: How do I find the width of the title displayed in the `UINavigationItem`?

**UPDATE:** I *have* found a solution to my problem, but it isn't exactly ideal, perfect, or reliable, so I am not marking it as an answer yet. If anyone has any better solutions, please share them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
self.navigationItem.title = title;

CGFloat titleWidth = 320 - (5.0 + self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.width + 10.0 + 10.0 + self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.width + 5.0);
if ([self.navigationItem.title sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"myfont" size:18.0]].width > titleWidth) {
    self.navigationItem.title = aShorterTitle;
}
```

Explanation: `titleWidth` is a manual calculation of the amount of space left over for the title in the navigation bar. In other words:

> Total width of navigation bar (320) - (size of gap between back button and left side of screen (5) + width of back button + size of gap between back button and title (10) + size of gap between title and right bar button (10) + width of right bar button + size of gap between right bar button and right side of screen (5))

**Note:** The gap sizes (5 & 10) were measured manually and are accurate to the pixel, but Apple might change them slightly between software versions so this may not always be precise.

**Also note:** This solution caters for a navigation bar in portrait mode with a back button and one right bar button. If yours is different, you will have to tweak this manually.

As you can see, this is *not* a perfect solution, so if anyone has a better one, please share it.

Answer (score 2):

What I would try is, cast the `UINavigationItemView` to a `UILabel`, obtain the text of it with the `.text` property and get the `CGSize` of the string with the `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:`

```
UILabel *navItemView;
    for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
         if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationItemView")]) {
           navItemView = (UILabel*)view;
           CGSize theSize = [navItemView.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:navItemView.font.systemFontSize] constrainedToSize:260 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        }
}
```

Now you can use the `.width` property of `theSize` to find out the width of the text.

**NOTE:** This is theoretically speaking and not tested. I hope it works! Looking forward to how you make out with it. =)

Comment: Nope. `SIGABRT` `-[UINavigationItemView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Looks like it isn't a UILabel.